# How to attach value (deposit) to transaction with Nearlib?

Tags: nearprotocol

Let's say I have a contract function that expects a certain amount of near to be send with a certain transaction, the function is called `create_order`, `create_order` takes a couple arguments.

I have my contract setup in the frontend under the name `myContract`.

I want to call `myContract.create_order({...})` but the transaction fails because this method call doesn't have the right amount of NEAR tokens attached.

How do I assign a certain value of deposit to a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearlib supports it using `account.functionCall(..., amount)`. But it might not work, because of the design of the access keys with function calls. Default authorized access keys towards applications only allows function calls without attached token deposits (only prepaid gas). It's done this way to prevent apps from automatically using your balance without your explicit approval. Details on access keys are here: https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs/blob/master/text/0005-access-keys.md

The way to attach a deposit for the transaction should be done with the explicit approval from the wallet. The app should create a request for the wallet, redirect to the wallet for the approval (or through the popup). Once user approves the transaction, it's signed with full access key from the wallet directly and broadcasted. But I'm afraid we don't have this API on the wallet yet. Issue for this: https://github.com/nearprotocol/near-wallet/issues/56

Comment: I simplified my code, in my actual project I do first gain an acces key from the sender by logging into the wallet.

Comment: There is NEP for explicit transaction signing by user (needs to be updated as we don't use photos anymore):
https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs/pull/10/files?short_path=cfb6900#diff-cfb6900ae98b312990611d3adb2f1b90

This is yet to be implemented on wallet / nearlib side though.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to use `account.functionCall` directly (without sugar for RPCs) to either attach amount or specify gas allowance for the call.

See [Account#functionCall](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearlib/blob/5251dca0f00415deb38852c25daafe698eef03b4/src.ts/account.ts#L150) in nearlib.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not supported at the moment. It will be available after this NEP https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs/pull/13 lands.