# How to send near tokens to payable function in near api js and near cli?

Tags: nearprotocol

I have a following function in the contract:

```
#[payable]
pub fn buy_tokens(&mut self) {
    let amount = env::attached_deposit()
}
```

But how to call the function in near-api-js and near cli with attached near tokens deposit?

```
await nearvar.contract.buy_tokens()
```

Edit:

```
await nearvar.contract.buy_tokens({}, GAS_AMOUNT, ATTACHED_DEPOSIT);
```

Gives error  {InvalidTxError: {InvalidAccessKeyError: "DepositWithFunctionCall"}
The error seems because of function call action is not allowed with a function call access key https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/integrator/errors/error-implementation

How to call payable function with full access keys?

This is my index file: [Link](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdUe4sWAhHomhVeqNQigeWX8U86TNJprnnu48Qco9gd8A/index.js)

This is where I am calling the function: [Link](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdUe4sWAhHomhVeqNQigeWX8U86TNJprnnu48Qco9gd8A/components/BuyTokens/BuyTokens.jsx)

Comment: Seems it requires some wallet api, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911439/1566713 Not sure if api is already done.

Answer (score 3):

The second and third arguments of the functions in the `Contract` are gas and attached deposit:

```
await nearvar.contract.buy_tokens({}, GAS_AMOUNT, ATTACHED_DEPOSIT);
```

Or you can use the `Account` API ([see details here](https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/developer/examples/near-api-js/examples#account)) to do that:

```
let account = await connection.account(senderAccountId);
account.functionCall(contractId, 'buy_tokens', {}, GAS_AMOUNT, ATTACHED_DEPOSIT);
```

where GAS_AMOUNT can be `100000000000000` for 100Tgas (can also pass null instead for default 30Tgas).
ATTACHED_DEPOSIT for example for 1N: `10000000000000000000000000`

Comment: await nearvar.contract.buy_tokens({}, 100000000000000, 50); gives following error: https://i.imgur.com/iiGD64M.png

Comment: this is error from transaction itself with very unfortunate parsing issue. you should be able to check in explorer or in the `Network` tab for more detailed error.

Comment: It gives {InvalidTxError: {InvalidAccessKeyError: "DepositWithFunctionCall"}}, I think it needs Full Access Key Instead of Function Call Access Key.

Comment: How to call payable function with full access key? https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdUe4sWAhHomhVeqNQigeWX8U86TNJprnnu48Qco9gd8A/index.js