# Attach deposit in near cli

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to call transfer function using near cli.

But this command does not work:

```
near call $ID transfer '{"new_owner_id":"amiyarust.testnet", "amount":50}' --accountId amiyatulu.testnet
```

"transfer" is a payable method requires an attached deposit.

```
  #[payable]
    pub fn transfer(&mut self, new_owner_id: AccountId, amount: U128) {
        // NOTE: New owner's Account ID checked in transfer_from.
        // Storage fees are also refunded in transfer_from.
        self.transfer_from(env::predecessor_account_id(), new_owner_id, amount);
    }
```

The near call command gives following error:

```
panic_msg: "panicked at 'The required attached deposit is 38600000000000000000000, but the given attached deposit is is 0', src/avrit.rs:1026:13"
```

I already questioned a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598492/how-to-send-near-tokens-to-payable-function-in-near-api-js-and-near-cli/), but unable to find a working solution or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to attach deposit to a call, it should be done as a command-line argument, i.e, the call should look like

```
near call $ID transfer '{"new_owner_id":"amiyarust.testnet", "amount":50}' --accountId amiyatulu.testnet --amount 50
```

The `amount` argument you have in your contract method does not bear any significance in regards to attached tokens.

Comment: Yes, worked. Thank you so much. Can you please help me out in doing it with near-api-js . How to call payable function in near-api-js? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598492/how-to-send-near-tokens-to-payable-function-in-near-api-js-and-near-cli/

Comment: near call has two options --gas --amount, sorry I missed reading it.  https://docs.near.org/docs/development/near-cli#near-call